# Best way to perform distributed SQL query and joins, calling from .Net code

Tags: sql-server, performance, linq, ssis, linked-server

Here's my scenario:

I have to query two PeopleSoft Databases on different servers (both are SQL Server 2000) and do a join of the data. My application is a .Net application (BizTalk).

I'm wondering what the best option is with regards to performance?

1. use standard select queries to get data
   and do the join in memory (e.g. LINQ) for example
2. generated complex dynamic queries using LINKED Server, e.g.

   select blah 
   from Server1.HRDB.dbo.MyTable1 
   left join Server2.FinanceDb.dbo.MyTable2
3. use standard select queries to get the data into an intermediate / staging sql server database and do my queries / joins on this database instead.
4. should I consider using SSIS? ( are there features here that might be better than doing an in-memory, e.g. LINQ? )
5. I wish I could use stored procedures on the source database, but the owners of the PeopleSoft database refuse it

The main constraints we have is that the source database is old (SQL Server 2000) and that performance of the source database is paramount. Whatever queries I run on this server must not block the other users. Hence, the DBAs are adamant about no Stored Procedures. They also believe that queries involving Linked Servers will trump (i.e. take higher priority) to other queries being run against the the database.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Update: additional background information on the project
We are primarily integrating PeopleSoft databases (the HR and Finance) into another product. Some are simple - like AccountCode and Department. Others are more complex, like the personal data, job, and leave accrual. Some are real-time, other's are scheduled, and other's are 'batch' (e.g. at payroll runs).

Regardless, we have to get source data out of PeopleSoft database -- and my hope had been to let the (source) database do the 'heavy' lifting by executing SQL Queries. I don't really want BizTalk, or SSIS, or C# LINQ to be the ones doing the transformations/filtering.

Definitely open to suggestions.

Comment: If your dba's believe that only stored procedures block users, then they are idiots. Feel free to reference this comment when you tell them so

Comment: That said, your problem is that you need to bring this data together with minimal impact to your users. Normally, I would ask how much latency they can incur but I'm certain you'll say they need real-time to the millisecond, yes? If that's the case, then you're stuck between a rock and very hard place. Querying the data, regardless of stored procedure or dynamic sql, is going to acquire locks. Locks lead to blocking until queries are done. At my  client, we are dealing with PS on DB2 for zOS. We take the approach of snapshotting data at 3 in the morning into staging tables and work from there.

Comment: Linked server challenge is going to be that to make it efficient, you need to pass your criteria to one of the servers for filtering. Otherwise, you'll be streaming the entire table to the "other" server and then filtering there (where you won't get the benefit of indexes).

Comment: I second Bill's opinion regarding said DBAs, but not only regarding blocking, but also regarding "They also believe that queries involving Linked Servers will trump (i.e. take higher priority) to other queries being run against the the database.". That's sheer BS. Now, you could run your queries using NOLOCK (on the target, using views or procs, see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fbc52b71-a084-4315-9bb5-ebcb8e745c0a/with-nolock-across-a-linked-server)), your users won't be blocked by your queries.

Comment: If you can get more specific, maybe you only need PS_POSITION_DATA from server A and PS_PAY_CHECK from server B, then maybe we can look at how you can approach this differently but a generic solution is probably not within the scope of these forums. (happy to be proven wrong)

Comment: I would pick option 3 and do all the lifting with SQL jobs.

Comment: Just a note -- this is SQL Server 2000, so I have to respect the DBAs when they tell me about the stored proc / linked server performance issues. I haven't worked with this database in excess of a decade!